# incorrect result of fast dct algorithm

Tags: performance, vhdl, dct

I want to implement the Loeffler fast dct algorithm by VHDL. Prior that i checked the algorithm result for a given data such below:

```
x=[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
```

then i calculated dct equivalent using this algorithm and result be came:

```
y=[28  -8.47  0  -4.6638  0  10.43  0  -5.966 ]
```

but the resut of matlab is this:

> > y=dct(x)

y =

Columns 1 through 6

```
9.8995   -6.4423         0   -0.6735         0   -0.2009
```

Columns 7 through 8

```
     0   -0.0507
```

what's my mistake?

thanks

Comment: Well, one of your mistakes is expecting that anyone will be able to diagnose the problem based on the information you've provided.

Comment: There appears to be no performance issue here and no VHDL issue either.

Comment: thanks for reply and excuse me for my bad information.

this is the algorithm:

http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQxPIt2zB6IwmSh64vnSPmEcIiw3_HnjC-1_lAj_sGiuaWjjjJM5A

so if we apply the above X vector to the input the result be came :

y=[28  -8.47  0  -4.6638  0  10.43  0  -5.966 ]

while the matlab result say it isn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation calculates the unnormalized DCT-II. You can simply multiply with the following formula to normalize your results:

[image: 1]

Your results should now be:

```
y = [9.899  -4.235  0  -2.316  0  5.215  0  -2.983]
```

For sure the result isn't equal to matlab, your Loeffler results should be something like this:

```
y = [28  -12.8846  0  -1.3469  0  -0.4018  0  -0.1014]
```

Source:
https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.5.2/en_US/dct.html

Comment: The unnormalized DCT-II  would yield the vector `56., -25.77,   0.,  -2.69,   0.,  -0.8,   0.,  -0.2` so that can't be what OPs code is computing.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why the result of  Loeffler algorithm not as same as matlab result.

BTW, in this page:

http://calculator.vhex.net/post/calculator-result/discrete-cosine-transform

Entered sequence a:
i    ai
1   0
2   1
3   2
4   3
5   4
6   5
7   6
8   7
Result :
i
1   56
2   -25.769292
3   0
4   -2.693819
5   0
6   -0.803612
7   0
8   -0.202809

the result isn't matched to any result of matlab or Loeffler algorithm!!!

i really confused. why each of which have a result that not matched to others.

Comment: you have to divide the results by 2 and then normalize the results like you can see on my answer here to get the same result as you get from matlab